# Python regex match keyword enclosed in quotation after another keyword enclosed in quotation

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and am trying to use regex to match a string.

```
string = '"formula_pretty":"MoS2"'
whatIsee =re.search(r'(?<="formula_pretty":").+(?= \")',string.group(0)
print(whatIsee)
```

What I want is for whatIsee to be MoS2, however, the re.search does not return any result. I think it's something to do with the quotation marks, but escaping them doesn't help.

Does anyone know what is the right way of writing this re.search code?

Answer (score 1):

Only an extra space in look ahead group `(?= \")` was leading to mismatch. Just make it this, and you don't have to escape `"` as you are always using raw string.

```
s = '"formula_pretty":"MoS2", "somethingelse":"blabla"'
whatIsee = re.search(r'(?<="formula_pretty":").+?(?=")', s)
print(whatIsee.group())
```

Prints,

```
MoS2
```

Comment: But https://regex101.com/r/xucUog/1 here it throws error when i don't escape `"`. May i know why i don't know python flavour of regex in very deep ?

Comment: @CodeManiac: Escaping is needed only if you don't use raw strings. But as OP is already using raw strings, escaping is not needed. `r` before a string makes the string raw in python.

Comment: But here r" is also added before regex check the link once.

Comment: @CodeManiac You can change r" to r', just click on it in regex101.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thanks i wasn't aware of that.i have updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi! Your solution definitely works. However, I noticed that the .+(?= \") is search for the " from the back of the string.
For example, if 
    string = '"formula_pretty":"MoS2", "somethingelse":"blabla"'
the output will be 
    MoS2", "somethingelse":blabla 
instead of MoS2. How can I ask for the output to be only MoS2?

Comment: @Jacek: Yes by default the quantifiers are greedy. If you want to make it capture the very first double quote, change it to `.+?` instead of `.+` [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qc9Xfr/1) Updated my answer too with non-greedy quantifier regex.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Your reply comes even before I can complete editing my question haha.  It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate**

```
(?<="formula_pretty":").+(?=")
```

**What you missed in your regex.**

- There was one extra space `(?= \")` in this part.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xucUog/2)

**P.S:-** @Pushppendra For telling difference between r" and r'

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '"formula_pretty":"MoS2"'
match = re.search(r'(?<=:)\s*"(.+?)"', string).group(1)
```

***EDIT: Include explanation:***

https://regex101.com/r/l50w8A/1

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.